# Calling MAPI email from Delphi 64 bit app does not work when same code for Delphi 32 bit app works?

Tags: delphi, email, outlook, delphi-xe2, 32bit-64bit

I am building a 64 bit Delphi XE2 app to handle sending MAPI mail through Outlook. This is intended for 64 bit installs of Outlook 2010, 2013, etc. because you cannot call 64 bit MAPI from a 32 bit app.

I have Delphi code that functions perfectly with 32 bit versions of Outlook clients when compiled as a 32 bit app. 32 bit apps are running on Win7 64.

The code always fails with a MAPI_E_FAILURE error code which is 2 when the same code is recompiled into a 64 bit app. The 64 bit app is running on Win 8 with Outlook 2013 64 bit client installed.

Any ideas why the 64 bit app fails? Am I doing or not doing something obvious regarding 64 bit code?

Cheers!
TJ

Here is the code:

```
function SendEMailByMAPI(SenderName, SenderAddress, Subject, Body: Ansistring; Recipients, Attachments: TStringList): Integer;
var i: Integer;
var EmailMessage: TMapiMessage;
var lpSender: TMapiRecipDesc;
var MAPI_Session : Cardinal;
var RecipientArray : array of TMapiRecipDesc;
var AttachmentsArray : array of TMapiFileDesc;
begin
  FillChar(EmailMessage, SizeOf(EmailMessage), 0);

  //add sender address if not blank.
  if (SenderAddress <> '') then begin
    lpSender.ulRecipClass := MAPI_ORIG;
    if (SenderName <> '') then begin
      lpSender.lpszName := PAnsiChar(SenderAddress);
    end
    else begin
      lpSender.lpszName := PAnsiChar(SenderName);
    end;
    lpSender.lpszAddress := PAnsiChar(SenderAddress);
    lpSender.ulReserved := 0;
    lpSender.ulEIDSize := 0;
    lpSender.lpEntryID := nil;
    EmailMessage.lpOriginator := @lpSender;
  end;

  EmailMessage.lpszSubject := PAnsiChar(Subject);
  EmailMessage.lpszNoteText := PAnsiChar(Body);

  EmailMessage.nFileCount := Attachments.Count;
  SetLength(AttachmentsArray, Attachments.Count);
  //Loop and add file path and name
  for i := 0 to Attachments.Count-1 do begin
    AttachmentsArray[i].nPosition := Cardinal(-1);
    AttachmentsArray[i].lpszPathName := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(Attachments[i]));
    AttachmentsArray[i].lpszFileName := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(ExtractFileName(Attachments[i])));
  end;

  if EmailMessage.nFileCount > 0 then begin
    EmailMessage.lpFiles := Pointer(AttachmentsArray);
  end
  else begin
    EmailMessage.lpFiles := nil;
  end;

  SetLength(RecipientArray, Recipients.Count);
  for i := 0 to Recipients.Count-1 do begin
    RecipientArray[i].ulReserved := 0;
    RecipientArray[i].ulRecipClass := MAPI_TO;
    RecipientArray[i].lpszName := StrNew(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(Recipients[i])));
    RecipientArray[i].lpszAddress := StrNew(PAnsiChar('SMTP:' + AnsiString(Recipients[i])));
    RecipientArray[i].lpEntryID := nil;
    RecipientArray[i].ulEIDSize := 0;
  end;

  EmailMessage.nRecipCount := Recipients.Count;
  EmailMessage.lpRecips := Pointer(RecipientArray);

  //Send the message
  Result:= MapiLogon(Application.Handle, PAnsiChar(''), PAnsiChar(''), MAPI_LOGON_UI or MAPI_NEW_SESSION, 0, @MAPI_Session);
  if (Result = SUCCESS_SUCCESS) then begin
    ShowMessage('Before calling MAPISendMail');//used as a timing device to see how long it takes for Outlook to respond to request and show email dialog
    Result := MAPISendMail(MAPI_Session, Application.Handle, EmailMessage, MAPI_DIALOG or MAPI_LOGON_UI , 0);
    if Result <> 0 then begin
      case result of
        MAPI_E_AMBIGUOUS_RECIPIENT : ShowMessage('Receiver is not unique.');
        MAPI_E_ATTACHMENT_NOT_FOUND : ShowMessage('File for appending not found');
        MAPI_E_ATTACHMENT_OPEN_FAILURE : ShowMessage('File could not be opened for appending.');
        MAPI_E_BAD_RECIPTYPE : ShowMessage('Type of receiver not MAPI_TO, MAPI_CC or MAPI_BCC.');
        MAPI_E_FAILURE : ShowMessage('Unknown Error.');
        MAPI_E_INSUFFICIENT_MEMORY : ShowMessage('Not enough memory.');
        MAPI_E_LOGIN_FAILURE : ShowMessage('User Login failed.');
        MAPI_E_TEXT_TOO_LARGE : ShowMessage('Text too large.');
        MAPI_E_TOO_MANY_FILES : ShowMessage('Too many file attachments.');
        MAPI_E_TOO_MANY_RECIPIENTS : ShowMessage('Too many recipients specified.');
        MAPI_E_UNKNOWN_RECIPIENT : ShowMessage('Receiver not found in the address book.');
        MAPI_E_USER_ABORT : ShowMessage('User canceled or MAPI Send not installed.');
      else
        ShowMessage('Error sending email. Error code: ' + inttostr(Result));
      end;
    end;
  end
  else begin
    ShowMessage('Failure to get MAPI call handle: ' + inttostr(Result));
  end;
end;
```

This function is called thusly:

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var SenderName: Ansistring;
var SenderAddress: Ansistring;
var Subject: Ansistring;
var Body: Ansistring;
var Recipients: TStringList;
var Attachments: TStringList;
begin
  Recipients := TStringList.Create;
  Attachments := TStringList.Create;

  Recipients.Add('test@test.com');
  Attachments.Add('c:\temp\test.xlsx');

  SenderName := 'TJ Asher';
  SenderAddress := 'sender@test.com';
  Subject := 'email test 64 bit subject';
  Body := 'Email test 64 bit body';
  SendEMailByMAPI(SenderName, SenderAddress, Subject, Body, Recipients, Attachments);
end;
```

Comment: Perhaps your records are mis-translated. We cannot see them. Your use of `StrNew` is wrong. It leaks. Create a `TList<AnsiString>` to store temp string values that you can cast with `PAnsiChar`.  Destroy the list in a finally block to tidy up.

Comment: This is posting code that might be good or bad, that depends on code that we can not see. If you who have the problem can not post even your perhaps working MAPI wrapper, nobody can help you.

Comment: @David Heffernan - not sure what you mean by mis-translated records? There are no records. I'll look at the `StrNew` bit as you suggest.

Comment: @Warren P - this is the entirety of the code. One function called by the button click code. The `MAPISendMail` call is all existing Delphi VCL code. I can post the Delphi VCL code if desired.

Comment: Sure there are records. You populate many different record types. The types are defined elsewhere. Perhaps they are wrongly declared packed, the second most common mistake that we see here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Sorry - I was thinking DB records, not record types. If you are referring to `TMapiRecipDesc` and `TMapiFileDesc` and `TMapiRecipDesc` those are all the pre-defined Delphi VCL code types as well. I can post those if desired? They don't appear to be declared as packed types. Perhaps some incompatibility between 32 and 64 bit record structures?

Comment: In which unit are these MAPI types and functions declared?

Comment: Isn't the MapiLogon function deprecated? I'm looking at source code of the first MAPI example found at this site (http://www.imibo.com/imidev/delphi/les/) and in it they use MapiLogonEx method instead. Also the comentary in the code is sugesting that MapiLogon is no longer available.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - they are defined in the Winapi.Mapi unit.

Comment: @SilverWarior - I'm not seeing anything in the Delphi XE2 VCL code that suggests MapiLogon is deprecated but I will try calling `MAPILogonEx` instead. At this point I'm willing to try most anything. Again all this code works perfectly under 32 bit.

Comment: Have you tried simplifying? Stripping out code until it starts working?

Comment: @TJAsher In the description of the you claim that you test your 32 bit version of your program on 64bit Windows 7 (you don't speciffy which version of Outlook you use there). But for 64 bit version of your program you claim that you use it on 64bit version of Windows 8 with 64bit version of Outlook 2013. So unless on Windows 7 you also have Outlook 2013 you can't even make comparison for figuring out why oin one case your program Works or not, since you are not interfacing with same version of the Outlook.

Comment: @TJAsher Also Delphi XE2 was released on 2nd of September 2011 which means that it is quite unlikely that its VCL has updated components for interfacing with Outlook 2013 since that hasn't even been realesed at the time those components were made.

Comment: @SilverWarior Why would it need to do that? This is MAPI. We aren't talking about Outlook automation.

Comment: It's possible that the XE2 WinApi MAPI wrapper units are not correct when used in 64 bit targets.

Comment: To continue the saga, (and thanks for all the replies so far) I tried to build a version with XE5 (one developer has a copy) and got the same results so I don't think it's the XE2 MAPI wrapper like Warren suggests. I will try stripping out things to see if I can even get Outlook to open a window as @DavidHeffernan suggested.

Comment: @SilverWarior I'm using Win 7 64 bit OS with Outlook 2003 32 bit client. Code that works with a 32 bit Delphi app when rebuilt as a 64 bit Delphi app does not seem to function at all with Win 8 and Outlook 2013 64 bit client.

Comment: The wrapper looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that MAPISendMail (A) is not a supported interface on Windows 8 64 bit:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/is-is/library/dd296721.aspx suggests that the Wide Character interface should be used.

It is also possible the MAPISendMail is not a supported interface on Outlook 2013 64 bit: It's been depreciated for a while. I'm not able to use that interface on Outlook 2013/64, but there are (as always with MAPI) complicating factors.